# Xperia Arc shows 3G signal but not connecting to Internet

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, internet, connection-issues, sony-xperia-arc

I have an Xperia Arc L15i about 5 months old, suddenly I have started experiencing problems with my 3G/2G service.

I have the *Access Points properly set up* (confirmed the same also with my service provider) and when I start the Data Service it shows up the 3G signal (full strength) but cannot connect to Internet.
Tried with the inbuilt browser, Opera mini and neither is the market accessible.

Network mode is **WCDMA/GSM** and even if try with **Only GSM** still its the same issue with 2G.

Is there anything else I need to look into or could it be a handset issue (not sure since I can see the H symbol). Any idea ?

**EDIT**

It seems i can access the net via WiFi, now i am puzzled (in case some wonder my data plan is valid)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what was the issue behind it, but i upgraded my Arc to 2.3.4 and surprisingly this made it work.

Just added it as an answer in case someone does come across any such thing.